# Incompatible pointertypes

Tags: ios, objective-c

since XCode 7 beta I get following error:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing "NSString" with an expression of type "NSURL"_Nullable
```

for this line of code:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

How to fix this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the docs for `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`. It returns an array of `NSURL` objects, not `NSString` objects. Simply adjust your code as follows:

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString *path = [url path];
```